# Combine two arrays and return items that is not in the first

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have this array:

```
categories = ['Cat A', 'Cat B', 'Cat C', 'Cat D']
```

And this array:

```
selectedCategories = ['Cat A', 'Cat D']
```

I want to produce a new array from this two:

```
categoriesAvailableToAdd = ['Cat B', 'Cat C']
```

Is there some neat underscore/lo-dash trick that does this? Can't find any. Must be a common task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`_.difference`](http://lodash.com/docs#difference) function, like this

```
console.log(_.difference(categories, selectedCategories));
# [ 'Cat B', 'Cat C' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

[_.difference](http://lodash.com/docs#difference):

```
_.difference([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10]);
// → [1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with an [array existence lookup function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {return a.indexOf(i) < 0;});
};
```

Your example:

```
var categories = ['Cat A', 'Cat B', 'Cat C', 'Cat D'];
var selectedCategories = ['Cat A', 'Cat D'];
categories.diff(selectedCategories);
// => ['Cat B', 'Cat C']
```